# Analyzing and Importing EEG Signals in Java

Tags: java, input, import

I am a beginner user of Java. I am currently working on a project and want to read a signal in java.

The signal type is the Electroencephalogram (EEG) signal obtained from an offline data set.

My questions:

> A)How to import (input) EEG signal in Java?

> B) Is there a library in Java for analyzing EEG signals?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why down vote, Please help me, as I mentioned I am a beginner user of Java. Thanks

Comment: Please provide: how do you get your input signal? Is the EEG connected somewho to your computer (USB?) and provides a possibility to read the signal?

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, but questions this broad don't usually do well on SO. SO generally works with well-defined questions that have factual answers. There probably are better places to ask "How do I get started..." questions than SO.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to read and parse the file, so it depends on the format of the file.
I don't know about a java library for reading eeg files, but if the data is in EDF or EDF+ format maybe this project can be a help: https://github.com/matthias-wright/edfconvis